# evaluating a cosine function using sine function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $\sin^2(\frac\pi9)+\sin^2(\frac{2\pi}9)+\sin^2(\frac{3\pi}9)+\sin^2(\frac{4\pi}9)=\frac94$, evaluate $\cos^2(\frac\pi9)+\cos^2(\frac{2\pi}9)+{}$ $\cos^2(\frac{3\pi}9)+\cos^2(\frac{4\pi}9)$.

I know the identity $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$

I am thinking of replacing $\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{9})$ with $1-\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{9})$ and replacing the same identity for each sin.

like this:

$$\Big(1-\cos^2\big(\frac{\pi}{9}\big)\Big) +\Big(1-\cos^2\big(\frac{2\pi}{9}\big)\Big)+\Big(1-\cos^2\big(\frac{3\pi}{9}\big)\Big) +\Big(1-\cos^2\big(\frac{4\pi}{9}\big)\Big) =\frac{9}{4}$$

and then: when moving i will get:

$$\cos^2\big(\frac{\pi}{9}\big)+\cos^2\big(\frac{2\pi}{9}\big)+\cos^2\big(\frac{3\pi}{9}\big)+\cos^2\big(\frac{4\pi}{9}\big)=1+1+1+1+\frac{9}{4}=4+\frac{9}{4}=\frac{25}{4}$$

Does this seem right?

Comment: The idea is good, but the sum should be $4-\frac{9}{4}=\frac{7}{4}$. Note that $\cos^2 x\le1$ for all real $x$, so the sum of four such terms cannot exceed $4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not right. There is an error in the last step, you should subtract $\frac{9}{4}$ as follows

$$\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{9}\right)+\cos^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{9}\right)+\cos^2\left(\frac{3\pi}{9}\right)+\cos^2\left(\frac{4\pi}{9}\right)=1+1+1+1-\frac{9}{4}=\frac{16-9}{4}=\color{blue}{\frac{7}{4}}$$